# Identify these little bugs on my cherry tree (and others)

Tags: pest-control, bugs

I have three trees in large pots. A medlar, an apple tree, and a pear tree.

On my cherry tree I found some weird bugs . I would like to know which kind of bugs im dealing with here, so I can get rid of them, if I have to.

[image]

Last year, I had some sort of bug on my medlar tree. It curled up in the leaves, and basically destroyed the tree. The leaves ended up looking like little cocoons for the bugs.

This year I really want to avoid the trees to look ugly during bloom and throughout summer.

I notice I'm having more and more bugs on my plants this year, and not all of them look the same. I can post pictures of the others one if need be, too.

Thanks for the answers,

Edit; I just went and checked the trees again, and the cherry tree is becoming quite infested at the highest leaves with these black bugs. They settle around the central nerve of the outer leaves.

Comment: What you use for soil in these pots? ONLY sterilized potting soil should be used in pots, period. How large are your pots and do you plan to eventually plant them in the garden soil? We need to talk about that.

Comment: I have used regular soil you can buy in bags from the store for my trees. The cherry tree is one I have gotten as a gift a couple of years ago, and I have no idea which soil it has. I will measure the pots and put some updated information here asap.

Comment: Potting soil is great.  Probably want to change out the soil of your gift tree.  As soon as you can while you are able to maneuver that pot.  Please send pictures of the trees in their pots.  Are they in the sun or are they under a patio roof?  Have you fertilized ever?  Bamboo is correct, a stressed tree is vulnerable to insects and disease.  What are your plans for the trees?

Answer (score 4):

That pest appears to be Black Cherry Aphid,and it will be very active and highly visible at this time of year. I didn't realise it could be a problem in Europe- this link has a great picture http://barmac.com.au/problem/black-cherry-aphid/ but its an Australian site, so the recommended treatment in the link probably isn't  available where you are. You'll have to do some research, or ask at the garden centre, what might be an appropriate treatment for your area. If this is a fruiting cherry, best not to use a systemic insecticide, but if its just ornamental, then systemic treatments aren't a problem.

Hopefully your potted trees are dwarf or patio varieties - if not, keeping them in pots means they are much more likely to suffer insect and other problems because they cannot develop a good root system.

Answer (score 0):

Cherry aphids.Pottted trees tend to be bothered by pests.